# Camel: Ignore some messages in mock endpoint

Tags: java, mocking, apache-camel

I have to unit test a component that sends 3 messages to a mock endpoint, but i only want to test the second message and ignore the others. How can i do this? i know, that there will be three messages. i dont care about the first and the third one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/mock.html), you can use `mock.message(1)` to set assertions and perform tests on the second received message.